# CSS Triangle with 3 Colors

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Respected,
I Have 3 Colors in my Laravel blade template, And I want to generate a triangle with them, exactly in

[image: This shape]

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dyNwgBj

Comment: Sir, I did Google, I searched on StackOverflow, I got some helping content but still was not able to do what I wanted.
I wrote what I need, I have 3 colors and have to make the same shape div.

Comment: You have to **demonstrate** what you tried. Just asking is not sufficient.

Comment: I did my best to demonstrate in simple words and got what I was looking for, Anyways thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Demonstrate your CODE attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shape is only what you want you can do this.

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 150px solid red;
  border-top: 150px solid red;
  border-right: 150px solid green;
  border-bottom: 150px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: JazakAllah, much appreciated bro, Thank you so so so so so much!!!